# Throwing fatal error "'Class 'Breadcrumbs' not found" in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migrate

I converted my application from Laravel 5.0 to Laravel 5.2. I created laravel 5.2 project through the command prompt. And copied model, view and controllers from old application. Next gave full permission to storage folder.
Now the issue is, while run the project after login its throwing fatal error like "'Class 'Breadcrumbs' not found". How can I fix that?

**Update:**

I update `app.php` file with below code

```
'providers' => [
    .....
    DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::class
],
'alias' => [
    .....
    "Breadcrumbs" => DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Facades\Breadcrumbs::class 
]
```

But now another error is coming like,

```
Class 'DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

code below in your composer.json

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "laravel": {
          "providers": [
              "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider"
          ],
          "aliases": {
              "Breadcrumbs": "DaveJamesMiller\\Breadcrumbs\\Facades\\Breadcrumbs"
          }
      }
    }
},
```

to your `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
        .....
        DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::class
],
'alias' => [
        .....
        "Breadcrumbs" => DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Facades\Breadcrumbs::class 
]
```

Comment: Class 'DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider' not found - Now this error is showing

Comment: `composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.x`

Answer (score 0):

Prepend a `\` like `\DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsServiceProvider::class`.